# How to use the_excerpt in a filter hook?

Tags: filters, hooks, excerpt

I was hoping to process the_excerpt just like one would with the_content, but no such luck.

How can I pass the excerpts of a Posts Page, through my plugin?  I've tried variations on this:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'my_function');
```

But alas, no go.  Suggestions?

**EDIT:  It looks like my filter call won't work when called from within another function, but it DOES work if it's at the same level of the function I'm calling, like so:**

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'my_filter');

function my_filter($content) {
    die('hello');
}
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: you can filter the excerpt that way, what does your function look like?

Comment: Well actually it's quite a complex series of functions, but I already have them running just fine on the_content, the_title, wp_title, and wp_head so I figured if the_excerpt was valid, it should just work.  Maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm looking at the static posts page?  Do the excerpts on that particular page behave differently?

Comment: they all use the same function, `the_excerpt` just applies default filters to `get_the_excerpt` which can also be filtered. use [`has_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_filter) and make sure nothing is removing filters from `the_excerpt`. try just a simple function and throw a `die()` in there or something.

Comment: Just did exactly that... tried a super simple function "die('hello');" and it does nothing.  Not sure what's amiss here...

Comment: what do you see if you add `global $wp_filter; print_r($wp_filter['the_excerpt']);` in your template?

Comment: Too many characters to paste, so here's an image:  http://screencast.com/t/dphcYjJO

Comment: Whoops!  Looks like I had some other logic that was abandoning execution if there was no post_id, which there isn't on the posts page.  Removed that and things work just fine running on the_content, no need to process excerpts separately.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you don't want to code it by yourself, you could use a plugin like Custom more link complete:
[wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-more-link-complete/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-more-link-complete/ "Custom more link complete")

Answer (score 7):

use the filter `get_the_excerpt`. Look at line no. 250 [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-template.php), they are using `the_excerpt` internally on the function `get_the_excerpt()`, and in this function on line no. 272, they're applying the filter `get_the_excerpt` on the actual excerpt. Hence,

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'exc');

function exc($param) {

    return "Whew !".$param;
}
```

is the way to go if you want to filter excerpts!