# How Can A Plugin Hook Itself To the End of Every Excerpt?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, the-content, excerpt

So far, I've been able to only consistently hook the_content, appending my plugin at the end. How can I test if the displayed article is not the_content, but an excerpt, and hook my plugin after every the_excerpt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the\_excerpt in a filter hook?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30380/how-to-use-the-excerpt-in-a-filter-hook)

Answer (score 1):

From the codex there are a couple of possible filters for you to try:

- [get_the_excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt)
- [the_excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_excerpt/) - look at @Mayeenul's [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30380/how-to-use-the-excerpt-in-a-filter-hook) for usage suggestions

Personally I would try the first one with something like:

```
function fileterExcerpt($excerpt){
    if(has_excerpt()){
        $excerpt .= "Some extra text";
    }
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'filterExcerpt' );
```

Hope this helps.